# What's the justification for rejecting this answer edit?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I had an [answer edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7971885) rejected because "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

What does that mean anyway?

To make things even funnier, the answerer himself later made the change a few short hours after my edit flagged up in his notification.

Might have the moderators just blindly rejected the edits because it looks trivial?

Comment: s/moderators/reviewers/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're changing code in someone else's answer. Such an edit changes the *meaning* of the answer, and is anything but trivial. Reviewers don't necessarily have the domain knowledge to judge the technical veracity of an edit (or indeed, the original answer), so they cannot guarantee that your edit doesn't end up making the answer worse off than it currently is.

Unlike other reviewers, the author of an answer is often in the best position to judge technical edits. This is why they can either approve or reject an edit overriding all other decisions, or they can apply a rejected edit they deem suitable after the fact.

If you believe code in an answer needs to be modified, either post a separate answer with the correct code, or leave a comment on the answer explaining why you think it should be changed. Leave the actual edit up to the author.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to elaborate on what would otherwise sound like a very curt and bureaucratic answer.

Comment: Nonsense. **Reviewers who lack the domain knowledge should skip, not reject**. As stated in the [policy](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), edits that “correct minor mistakes” are welcome. There is no exception for mistakes in code.

Comment: "they can apply a rejected edit they deem suitable after the fact" - is there a UI affordance for this? I couldn't find it. I had to make the change manually myself, duplicating the effort.

Comment: @Gilles: while I wholeheartedly agree with your comment, the current state of the policy you've linked to doesn't mention anything about the mechanics of reviewing edits. Is there a better link?

Comment: @Dan Dascalescu: Nope, sadly.

Comment: @DanDascalescu That's a policy, not a help manual. The mechanics are very briefly presented in the [edit privilege description](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) and in more detail in the meta FAQ on [suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) and [review queues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work).

Comment: @Gilles: I meant that skipping wasn't mentioned in the policy.

Comment: @DanDascalescu It's mentioned in the official documentation for [reviewing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) but not recalled in the section on reviewing suggested edits in the official documentation for [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, many reviewers on Stack Overflow systematically reject edits that correct mistakes in code, even if the correction is simple and obvious. This is contrary to the [official rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) which encourage edits that “correct minor mistakes”.

Please do edit posts to correct minor mistakes. If the mistake is major, so that the edit would require substantially changing the post, downvote and post an answer of your own. If the mistake is minor, which is the case here, edit. Editing is a very important aspect of Stack Exchange: it's how we can collectively make answers better by pooling our knowledge.

You should always explain why what you're changing needed changing in your edit summary, which you did, thank you.

I assume that your correction is itself correct (especially given that the original poster made the same edit later). Of course, edits that introduce a mistake should be rejected. I would have skipped this review because I lack the subject knowledge to verify it.

I have no idea why reviewers picked this rejection reason (“attempt to reply”). It's intended for edits that attempt to reply to an answer, not for incorrect or overarching edits — the correct reason for that is “clearly conflicts with author's intent”.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. I would like to agree with you too - creating a new answer just because it "changes the code" sounds pretty egoistic and probably lacks the visibility that an original (but flawed) answer would have. It wouldn't have been very useful. Although the system still sounds inflexible, the fact that you moderators take the time to discuss this means that not all is lost. Thanks!

Answer (score -7):

Your edit answers the question. It should be posted as an answer, not as an edit.

The message you quote here is pretty clear about this.

Comment: So what kind of edits would not make an answer?

Comment: Why not spend some time learning about what an edit is as opposed to an answer? You seem to be very confused.

Comment: This is an edit to an answer, not a question. The issue isn't that they're editing an answer into a question, it's that they're changing the code of someone else's answer in a non-trivial way.