# Why would I make a new answer when all I want to do is supplement an existing one?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I often try to update or extend answers when I have a small contribution to someone else's work.

I do this because

1. I want to give credit, not compete with an already good answer
2. I don't think my contribution amounts to enough to be a significant difference;  I would essentially copy the existing answer and then add a tiny bit to it.

But I often get rejected "intended to address the author...should have been a comment or [else a new] ...answer.

Today I have another very good example of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18652032

Is this rejection on track?
If so, what is the point of editing?  For very similar answers, are we not trying to work together to end up with one best version?

I've seen [What's the justification for rejecting this answer edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295432/whats-the-justification-for-rejecting-this-answer-edit) but I'm not really asking about changing code. I'm asking about editing to extend the answer, without changing it at all.

I'm presenting my example today because it is exactly the edge case I'm talking about.   If we want to talk about code edits particularly, it's a great example for my question because I didn't
**change** anything.    I specifically did a minor but meaningful extension, because it was hard to find but very useful.    If I made a new answer, I would have to entirely copy the answer I edited.      This raises my point -- should I really make that a new answer? If not, why not an edit?

---

> I appreciate all the feedback about my linked example.  I certainly
>   will take the advice about better commenting;  I'm not arguing with
>   anyone about that.
>
> It would be great to see more answers about
>   the root question.
>
> Assume your own perfect small addition -  correct information, perfect
>   style, perfect comments, inserted the perfect place...
>   ...and
>   changing nothing of the original answer and requiring all of it.
>
> Is that a New Answer or an Edit?

Comment: Have you read any of the many "related" questions and answers?

Comment: Yeah, but I've also read some of the Edit guideline questions and I don't feel it's consistent so I'm raising it again.  I many cases feel I am exactly "migrating information from comments so it is all in the answer" or "clarifying code without changing the intent", as per Edit guidelines.

Comment: To be honest, this edit doesn't make much sense to me. I don't know C# (or whatever language this is), but it looks like it adds two useless variables without any explanation why they are necessary. I would reject that as well.

Comment: In the example I gave from today (China time) ,  I added code that was absolutely an extension of the answer.  It fully depends on the answer, but adds new, important information (essentially a different format of the output) which is meaningful because it isn't easy to find (I spent a good bit of time to find it).  A previous comment also requested the same output.  If I added a new answer, I would have to entirely copy this Answer to get to my part, which I feel is not on track.

Comment: @yivi -  In fact, that link is different in the important ways I mention.  I'm asking with my example today because it is exactly to the edge case I'm talking about.  If we want to talk about code edits particularly, it's a great example for my question because I didn't _change_ anything.  As I said, I specifically did a minor but meaningful extension, because it was hard to find but very useful.  This raises my point --  should I really make that a new answer?  If not, why not an edit?

Comment: @Tom -  In that case, should you not Skip because you "lack domain knowledge"?  Indeed, you don't get the point.  The question is how to get duration values for video files.  The Answer I touched is one great way to do it, but it stops with only a special output string, and not an actual numeric duration.  I found the numeric duration, continuing exactly from where the Answer stopped.  It's actually very clear - read the variable names - if you take the time to understand the Question and the Answer.

Comment: But certainly, if it is a problem with clarity,  then that still just comes back to my original question...  why was this rejected as "comment to author" / "new answer"

Comment: The answer in the dupe target answers your question. You should read it.

Comment: @yivi -- I have updated to explain again.  My comments and my edit explain the difference from the duplicate.

Comment: In the edit you are linking to as an example, you **did** add code, which is exactly the same as changing it. I'm not sure why you are saying you did not.

Comment: The variable names are very useless to me when you don't use them in any way or don't explain their purpose is in the code snippet. It would be a much better edit if you would add a new paragraph to ___explaining___ the additional way, combined with the two code lines and what they help to achieve. Just adding two lines of code in an existing code block without any explanation with just well-intentioned variable names, isn't useful on its own.

Comment: @yivi -- I'm exactly raising the issue of add compared to change.  Can we really improve Answers over time?  Is it always a competition, even down to adding just one line of code? (or 2)

Comment: @Tom --  I get your point.  It would definitely be better with some code comments.  But so why isn't the reject about that?  Then I would go back and make such improvements and we would move forward.  As it is, I don't see any reason to try again.  It seems like we are not welcome to evolve Answers.   (also, I did use the variables.  C# allows inline declaration and use.  Please do review the code carefully... perhaps part of the issue?)

Comment: No, the idea is not to "evolve" answers. You've got that right.

Comment: There is no "no code comments" reject reason ;P. I would also argue that the current reject reason can match the current situation: you're changing an existing code block which _might_ change the behaviour of that block and that can be against the intention of the original poster. A dedicated paragraph would have avoided that.

Comment: @yivi -  So are you saying I really should copy the whole previous answer and add 2 lines of code in a new answer?   Could you please vote to re-open and put that in an answer here?

Comment: @Tom - But the reject reason doesn't say "no changing code".  And, again,  what we're saying then is that if you don't understand the code at all, then reject...... I'm not sure that is the correct response.  Isn't that a case for "Skip" ?

Comment: There is no need to copy the other answer. You could refer/link to the other answer, explain what would you do different, write down the changed code and explain how is different... and you are done.

Comment: @yivi -  Ok....  so answers can be linked?   I understand that idea.  Is that in the faq/guides somewhere?

Comment: You can insert links to anything. HTML is like that. And if you are expanding on another's user's answer, I'd say it's good etiquette to acknowledge that answer and link it for better reference.

Comment: @yivi -  I understand your point.  So all-in-all, it sounds like you're saying Edits are only for formatting/typos/language.  Is that a fair statement?

Comment: @yivi "the idea is not to "evolve" answers" actually the idea is exactly that: [When should I edit posts? \[...\] Common reasons for edits include: \[...\] To correct minor mistakes or **add updates as the post ages**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Post are not supposed to be static blobs of text, since technology is always evolving. There's nothing in the help center that prohibits this, *au contraire* they encourage this.

Comment: @Braiam -  that page is what I'm talking about...  do we agree on this anymore

Comment: @Tom: It's not just the variable names, it's the types that make the point obvious.  The original code didn't do anything with `string duration` either, it was just a dead local like the `ulong` timecode and `double` time in seconds that Mike added.  I don't know C# either, but I know about strongly-typed languages, and this looks clearly useful, because it's going directly from the `prop` to a numeric, while the original only showed going directly to a string.  The only problem with the edit is that the changelog was too generic: it should have said "also show how to get numeric timestamps"

Comment: @MikeM Conversations about abstract "when should I do X or Y?  How should I do X or Y?" are rarely useful.  "How should I handle case Z?" is better, because the devil is quite often in the details.  Only after such advice, generalized manually by people using it, fails or succeeds should we ask general questions...

Comment: @MikeM I'm a C# guy and I would have done worst then you, i would have completely removed `string duration =` and replace it with only your `double durationInSec =`. It just doesn't make sense to ask a question about time and ask the output to be a string. But that is what the OP asked for... he asked for output in string (which is bad to me but i'm not judging) and the answer do return a string.

Comment: @PeterCordes "it's the types that make the point obvious" .. to you. It might be not that obvious for other readers. I get your point, but I don't think that adding dead variables is a good addition.

Comment: @Tom: IDK how much of my take on this is biased by seeing Mike's explanation *before* seeing the code.  It's definitely not a great edit, and would have been better with comments.  The original code wasn't great either; returning that string instead of just setting a dead variable would have been much better!  (Unless there's some C# reason for not doing that).  But comment + dead variable is not terrible.  (And better than just dead variable).  Anyway, I agree it's not obvious to everyone, and one problem with the review system is that reviewers don't get questions from tags they know...

Comment: @Yakk -- thanks for your feedback.  Indeed, for me, this was the latest of many such examples.  I have some free time now to push the discussion, so I posted.  I do feel it represents a big question, and something that has changed over time on SO (that I have a strong opinion about, of course ;) ).

Comment: @AntoinePelletier --  thanks for your feedback.  Yes, given my understanding that we should deliver a number (I took "13 minutes 12 seconds" as spelling out the data needed, not that s/he wanted a string)  I might have removed the pull to a string,  but I was very specifically avoiding changing the existing code.

Comment: @Tom --  The endpoint of setting the variables makes sense for the OP.  The question was to have the data.  The question does not specify anything about using it.  I realize if Reviewers aren't even shown the Question and won't spend the time to go look at it, then certainly Edits are going to have to spell it out.

Comment: I've just noticed that the `durationInSec` divides the initial value by 1e7, but @Tensibai's answer suggests it's microseconds, so we should be dividing by 1e6.

Comment: @KenY-N Or maybe it's actually 10^-7 and we need to lookup what prefix that is ;-) .  But that isn't very relevant to the bigger question.

Comment: Indeed it is, but since I'm waiting on a compile I just looked it up and 10e-7 might be either *decimicroseconds* or *hectonanoseconds*.

Comment: @KenY-N -  nifty :)  hah!  Doesn't even rate it's own unique name.  Don't know why they chose that...  maybe a fun new question as far as variable type size or something.  If you're using the object, note I don't know if there is typically that much precision (or even how the property is made) ...  that's just the units (easily verifiable with your own video files).

Answer (score 53):

I'm kind of summarizing @Tom's comments under the question (seen when reading the comment wall after writing the answer).

Let's take your edit as shown in review by markdown differences:

[image: Screenshot of the review markdown]

At this point as a reviewer, there's two more lines of code, likely doing nothing useful without even a comment above them to explain what they do.

Now reading the edit comment (which is a good point) I see:

> extended the code example to show another important way to access the same answer object

Ok, that makes sense, but this comment is necessary to understand the two lines of code and doesn't appear anywhere in the question. It won't help anyone.

As such the two lines of code are just noise, the best feedback is 'Tell the author in a comment they should add those alternatives or write your own answer'.

A proper edit could have been adding a paragraph looking like (with some guesses from my side; I may be wrong; that's just for the sake of exemple):

> Some alternatives to access the duration object are as follow
>   (depending on which type of value you wish to get):
>
> - `ulong rawDurationValue = (ulong)prop.ValueAsObject;` This one will give the value in microseconds as an unsigned integer
> - `double durationInSec = ( (ulong)prop.ValueAsObject ) / 10000000.0;` This one will return a float for the duration in seconds.

With this kind of edit I personally wouldn't be rejecting it as it is adding something to the answer to complement it and it comes with explanations. But at this point, it may also be another answer starting by 'To complement @nekno's answer....'.

Another option could have been to add code comments to self explain the new code lines and that they are here just for the sake of example like:

```
// Or in microsecond as an unsigned integer
ulong rawDurationValue = (ulong)prop.ValueAsObject;
// Or in seconds as a float 
double durationInSec = ( (ulong)prop.ValueAsObject ) / 10000000.0;
```

but this last form is even more a comment to the author as you may just have dropped a comment with them and told the author he should add them.

The choice of the rejection reason is to give 'advice'. We don't have myriad reasons tailored to everyone so sometimes the canned reason isn't exactly fitting. Try to look back at your edit and see what could have been done to avoid this rejection reason.

All in all try to think about people seeing the diff and that it should make sense for them and for future readers of the whole post. Don't just drop two lines of code. If you go to add information, really add information and if you don't feel writing a paragraph for them, just drop a comment so the post author may include it with his own words.

Comment: I agree that the inline comments and explanations make it much better.  But I have a hard time agreeing that "well, the Rejection reasons are just as good as they can be and we have to learn to interpret them".   My question is really raising the issue that both Reviewers and the Editors may no longer have a clear view of correct edits because they are learning from these reasons.  I would be very happy to get a clear Reject on the reasons you describe, and then go make such changes.  But today, I feel like it would still be rejected because the convention now is no-content-changes-allowed.

Comment: That is really what I'm talking about...  not this specific edit, but this type of edit.  Because this example is so simple  (and I have some free time now)  I'm using it to raise this issue.

Comment: @MikeM It seems like you didn't even read this answer - Tensibai very clearly laid out example edits similar to yours that would probably *not* be rejected, therefore your assertion that the convention is "no-content-changes-allowed" is baseless.

Comment: @Tensibai I like your points and I'd totally upvote, except I don't agree with the suggestion to make a new answer that references another one - answers should always stand on their own.

Comment: @Ajean -  And that is really my question.  I'm very sorry I didn't include code comments in my actual Suggested Edit.  But the bigger question is what is the meaning of such a small addition...... assume your own perfect small addition with excellent explanation and comments, and assume it is very strongly dependent on an existing answer --  should it be a new answer or an edit?

Comment: Note that the original code didn't do anything useful with `string duration` either, so adding 2 more initialized but then unused variables is not weird (for reviewers that took the time to read the code carefully; that's the problem).  Your proposed comments are a further improvement, and a less generic changelog message would have helped.

Comment: @MikeM what I mean is that it is your responsibility to avoid reviewers misinterpretation. When reviewing  a bunch of post reviewers probably don't wish to scroll dozen of reasons to reject. That's an indication and meta is here to give more details when needed.

Comment: @PeterCordes I deliberately omitted it from my answer because that doesn't really change the reception of the edit. I agree that's not really weird, but  that doesn't bring something useful neither without explanation :)

Comment: @ajean when you'll be saying the same thing as another answer, it is tolerated to reference another answer. If part of the other answer are needed for your own, then quote them and link to the quoted answer. The border between improvements edit and new answer is always moving, depending on who's making the decision/review :)

Comment: @Tensibai -- thanks again for your feedback and clarification

Comment: @MikeM you're welcome. Thanks for asking an open advice/explanation question, it's kind of rare lately as most are proposing changes instead of asking why it exist :)

Answer (score 15):

**TL;DR:** When you add new information to an existing answer, you are circumventing the voting which should take place on your answer. If you want to add to someone else's answer, write your own and indicate that you're supplementing an existing answer. There are two principal exceptions to this explained in detail at the bottom, regarding additional information found in comments, and to add updates if the answer becomes obsolete.

Your edits may very well be on point and correct additions to supplement the answer and make it better, however, by adding new information to an existing answer, you are (unintentionally in this case although some people could do it intentionally) evading the voting process where the community evaluates the value of your addition.

Think of it this way with a somewhat edge case example. Joe Billsman has an issue sees a question about his same that already has 5+ answers. He reads through the answers, but none of them fully fix his issue. After searching for a while, he figures out how to solve his problem. Wanting to make sure his answer is possible to find by others in his situation, he considers posting his answer, which is extremely similar to one of the highest voted answers with the exception of one or two steps that made all the difference for him.

But Joe stops to think, and sees that his answer will be all the way at the bottom of the page, harder to find for people with that problem. Joe thinks his fix is really important because it was essential to him, so to make sure it gets seen, Joe edits his answer into the similar high voted answer.

What's the issue here? The problem is that Joe's only source of judgement as to the usefulness of his solution is his own. Maybe the reason why that answer wasn't already there is because it is actually not all that useful to the general community, or because the answer was wrong and his "solution" just coincidentally fixed things (perhaps because of a misunderstanding the original problem). Or the answer could be just fine and valuable. But now, without any community input to validate or question that answer to see if it was good or not (through voting principally and possibly comments), Joe's answer is located inside a post with one of the highest vote counts. Joe is happy about that, because he thinks his addition to the answer is really important and deserves to be there, but the community hasn't evaluated the content that he has added, yet when someone looks at the answer, they'll see the high vote count are much more likely to trust the answer, which hasn't actually been evaluated by the community.

This case is kind of specific, but it demonstrates what happens when another person adds new content to an existing answer. It could be for any reason, like your own reason to add a meaningful extension to the existing solutions, or someone who wants to show a more efficient way to do the exact same thing. All of these are good things, however if you simply edit it into the answer, you sidestep the voting process, with your addition assuming the existing standing of the answer you edited.

The proper way to add new content (even little amounts) to an answer is to do as Tensibai suggested:

> ...at this point, it may also be another answer starting by 'To complement @nekno answer....'.

and thereby posting the content you want to add as a distinct answer, that way your addition can be evaluated for accuracy and usefulness by the community outside of the original answer.

Do note that this is a suggestion when you want to edit new material into an existing post. There are many, many reasons to edit posts to make them better, though "better" should not mean adding new material, rather, it should mean making what's there more presentable/clear.

**Two important exceptions to this:**
These are found on the [Help Center's Guide to Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

Editing is appropriate:

> To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place.

The most obvious time I see this done is when the OP has made a comment with more information to their own post without including it in their question. These can be integrated into the question easily since they are the OP's own words that you're just collecting into one place. I've also seen this done when post's comments are somewhat aged, where it is obvious that the OP has not acknowledged the comments, or they've explicitly accepted the comments but haven't edited their post to reflect it after a time. But use much caution when doing this, because you don't want to edit something into a question that the OP didn't add because they did not want it to be there.

> To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages

Leaning to the second half of adding updates as the post ages, this is also a special case that should be considered if an answer becomes obsolete. When it is actually appropriate to make these edits is discussed in length in [Good question, old version-dependent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer) and its linked questions.

Comment: I feel like this is still avoiding my question.  Yes, I'm making a judgement call that the addition is very much in line with the original answer and not "cheating" the system.  My question assumes that that judgement is correct......  is the Edit process able to handle that today or not?

Comment: @MikeM That's the entire issue: You are assuming your judgement is correct. You very well might be correct. But every person who posts an answer is assuming that they are correct, otherwise they wouldn't post to begin with. Is everyone correct? That's why we need the community to weigh in through voting on the material you add.

Comment: I get your point, and I think you have a good explanation along the lines that another user - yivi - was making in our original comments discussion ---  my type of "extension" should be a new answer that does indeed reference the other answer as a starting point.  I'm raising this question today because I don't personally agree with that.  In the "Help Center" guide you reference, the very first lines state that collaborative answers are entirely the goal.  My take on that is to add to the same answer rather than referencing.

Comment: A truly bad addition should be rejected.  But I'm raising the question of how to draw that line.  Do we have a common understanding, and it is being applied correctly?

Comment: I think your idea may fall under the first exception I pulled out from the help pages on editing. The addition should be added as a comment addressing the OP, then after a time, if the OP adds it then we're good, if the OP posts a comment saying that it's not in the spirit of their post then we've got our answer (The addition should not be edited in). If the OP simply doesn't respond for a long while, that's when we get into the grey area. Can we count upvotes on the comments as proof that the addition is appropriate to edit in? How 'long' is a 'long while'? It's a more complex judgement call.

Comment: The first lines of the Help Center's Guide to Editing state that "this site is collaboratively edited," but I don't see where it says, as you say, "collaborative answers are entirely the goal." The work of making a page of answers (multiple distinct answers) is definitely collaborative as each person provides their own answer, and every new correct answer makes the question more valuable. Edits are "for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date", and new answers are for giving different, new and better answers.

Comment: I would add, though, that when a post is made into a Community Wiki (Like an FAQ question), then an attempt it made to combine all the answers into one answer, though that is generally done after the separate answers have been voted on for their accuracy, and it is a long, complicated process. For example, [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254433/should-i-send-students-to-stack-overflow) was made a Community Wiki back in 2014 by the moderator animuson, and the Moderator Note found there was added, yet in nearly 4 years there are still 14 answers. It's a slow process.

Comment: I think those are very helpful points.  I'm still not sure I personally agree that individual answers aren't part of the collaborative editing.  I like that these different points are being articulated.  I think there are significantly different ideas out there being used, and that's my concern.  If we at least make them clear, we can start to understand it.  I hope to hear even more, especially to my original question.  Given a genuine small addition -  define that in your own perfect way if you don't like my linked example -  is that really best as a new answer and why.

Comment: @MikeM: The main solution to the trust problem of users making edits to existing answers is to earn enough rep that your edits don't have to go through a queue to be approved.  (It's 2k rep before you can edit posts).  With power comes responsibility, of course; only make such edits when you're familiar with the topic, usually not in something you're just learning yourself, to reduce the risk that you give future readers bad advice.  Edits will bump posts to the top, so people following the tag (instead of random reviewers with no domain knowledge!) could roll back your edit it it's bad.

Comment: @PeterCordes --  Thanks for the comment.  Indeed, this is one of the answers I expect:   there may be some case for editing content, but Suggested Edits are just going to be rejected without considering it that far...... it's really rejection-for-low-rep and not about any other criteria.  In all seriousness, if many people think that way, is the real answer to remove Suggested Edits entirely?  Why play games with Editors, and why have the Queue.  I might vote for that, in the name of consistency.

Comment: @MikeM: suggested edits that correct formatting, typos & grammar, and/or broken links very often get approved because anyone can see they're improvements even without any tag-specific knowledge.  There definitely is room for edits that actually change or add content, though.  I think if you'd added comments in the code, you would have had a good chance of having it approved, but it's still really frustrating when an edit you know is good is rejected by random jerks on the Internet with no score in the tag.  It's even dumber for tag-wiki edits, because those are still reviewed by anyone.

Comment: @PeterCordes -- it's good to know what kind of edits are easily welcome.  I'll keep that in mind in the future.  Yeah, it is frustrating sometimes :-).  That is the system that it's about slowly moving in the right direction across thousands of votes on different items..... but because Suggested Edits are just in or out (and with just a couple votes),  they are more frustrating to invest in today.  And I think that's too bad, because as the system ages, one might think Edits could be more and more important.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the rejections are on track. The point of edits are not to improve the technical quality of the code answer; that is you putting words in the answerer's mouth. Regardless of whether the answerer ultimately appreciates the edit, or whether you mean well, that is simply the wrong mechanism for sharing your contribution.

The point of edits is to fix typos, improve readability, and remove inappropriate markdown, grammar, language, etc.

### Edit a post:

- if its content is structured very poorly or doesn't make use of a Stack Snippet when it should.
- when there is a link that is dead and needs updating.
- when someone has asked a question in a very poor or confusing - way and you are able to understand what it is they are trying to get across.
- when there is inappropriate language or misspelled words, missing commas/periods, etc.
- when there is fluff such as "thanks", "hope this helps", "hi my name is ...", etc. that can be removed without losing any substantive information.
- to add information given by the poster in the comments that is relevant, pertinent, or otherwise useful as part of an answer or question.

### Do not edit a post:

- to add code, remove code, or change existing code.
- to change someone's indentation from two spaces to four spaces (or similar) or to move brackets to a new line, etc.
- to change someone's UK English spelling to US English spelling (or vice versa).
- to change the intent or meaning of the answer.

If you have code to recommend, either add an answer of your own, or simply add a comment under the answer suggesting the addition/change, and let the person who wrote the answer decide whether or not they want to add that code into their answer.

### The Exceptions:

- if the post is set to Community Wiki and the post has an invitation to edit and improve the post. CW posts are specifically designed to promote collaboration and remove any kind of meaningful "ownership" or reputation incentive for answering.
- if the code has been deprecated or replaced with a different method, or is dangerous/harmful to run, then it can be appropriate to edit it and add a caveat or a notice along with the new way to do it.

Comment: This remains bad advice: a prohibition on touching code on a site *primarily dedicated to Q&A involving code* hobbles the power of editing to expand and maintain existing information, a tool we desperately need to not be hobbled. Nearly every time this comes up, the root cause is an unclear purpose for the edit; please read [Tensibai's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362632/why-would-i-make-a-new-answer-when-all-i-want-to-do-is-supplement-an-existing-on/362646#362646), as it provides a much more nuanced perspective on this.

Comment: @Shog9 I disagree with the nuances in Tensibai's answer. I believe personal agency should remain important; if you want to change someone else's code, then ask them first. Though your comment does raise a good point about another exception.

Comment: Personal agency is always retained: an author may roll back a post they own at any time, and further holds the ability to unilaterally reject - or override prior approval - of suggested edits. Worrying about offending an author by altering their code is a reason to be explicit about why you're doing so - same as for modifying prose, which in practice I've seen far more people get offended about.

Comment: @Shog9 That much I agree with; it should be explicitly explained when adding code. I still maintain that a general "other way to do this" answer belongs by itself, but perhaps I'm jaded by the languages I answer in mostly; CSS is probably vastly different from C++, C#, etc. in this regard.

Comment: For sure, @tyler - for example, one of the most common pitfalls on certain platforms is the omission of error-handling from examples, even those in the official documentation. Good for brevity, bad when folks follow those examples slavishly! Altering such code when the problem becomes apparent can be a boon to future readers even though it doesn't change the critical information in the answer at all. This is where judging each edit on its own merits is so important.

Comment: thanks for the Answer.  I also appreciate the discussion in comments.  These are the questions I'm getting at.  I know there won't be some kind of final answer here, but I appreciate shining some light on the different perspectives.

Comment: And it's good to learn about "Community Wiki" as meaning broader leeway to change.  I did not know about that distinction.

Comment: "To add information given by the poster in the comments that is relevant, pertinent, or otherwise useful as part of an answer or question." As somebody who's suggested a lot of edits, these kind of edits often get rejected by at least one reviewer, though I wish this wasn't the case. "(Do not edit to...) add code, remove code, or change existing code." I see a lot of okayish answers in [c#] with (non-fatal) mistakes in code. Posting an answer that changes one or two lines of code arguably creates *more* editing work in the future because now there's two posts to maintain saying the same thing.

Comment: @jrh It's always better to err on the side of caution. I have also seen a lot of small non-fatal (and fatal) mistakes in code, but it's best to ask the poster "did you mean to write that? I think it should be X instead", because I have seen many cases where people assume the poster meant X and go ahead and edit it, and then edit wars start... But we should always use our best judgment and most of the time people have good intentions, so it's often a case of 'no harm - no foul'.

Comment: @jrh As for 'creating more work' by creating more answers, I think that's a non-sequitur. It's not your job to maintain other peoples' answers. If you want to, great. But you shouldn't be complaining that now there's two answers for you to check for errors rather than one... no one is making you do that.

Comment: @TylerH Right, I definitely wouldn't attempt to edit code where there's any possible benefit to the OP's approach, I was referring to cases like memory leaks caused by the lack of a `using` when the scope of the variable is limited to the sample code, code that forgot that .NET strings are case sensitive but Windows file names aren't, code that fails the [Turkey Test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html) -- those are the ones I recall offhand; posting a new answer to fix some of things feels like posting a dupe answer which is prohibited IIRC.

Comment: @TylerH the "creating more work" comment was sort of a big picture thing, not talking about my own work, it was moreso a concern about how well this will scale, considering the collective work required to keep the quality of this site's answers up. Worst case scenario, a single answer could turn into a series of flawed answers followed by a single usable one -- the first guy forgets a `using`, the second guy blindly uses `ToUpper()`, the third guy forgets something else, etc... and in the meantime the original post that barely works is sitting at +100/-10 because it happens to be the oldest.

Comment: @jrh In those situations I would probably agree; adding a missing Using statement is not the same as adding some code that is simply another way of doing what the previous code already did, with the reason of 'here's a new/different way to do this'. If you're *fixing* someone's answer, you get a lot more leeway than simply *changing* it.