# Should I edit an answer to incorporate a popular comment?

Tags: discussion, edits, editing-help

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14978871/1200649) is good, but would be even better if it incorporated the [top voted comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687035/css-bolding-some-text-without-changing-its-containers-size/14978871#comment22246662_14978871). The change is very small, only a couple of characters, but I'd also need to update the JSFiddle link with relevant code (or switch to a SO code snippet).

This change would optimise the answer, but the popular comment would no longer make sense - what's the best practice here? Edit or leave as-is?

Comment: I'm still not clear where the line is between improving an answer and putting words in someone's mouth but you shouldn't avoid editing improving an answer because of a comment. Just flag it as No Longer Needed. Good edits are more important than comments.

Comment: Including the snippet into the post is always a good thing. That said, I wouldn't replace the OP's code with the one in the comment, as that significantly changes how the answer renders. Maybe add it as another option.

Comment: @BSMP its a bit personal I guess. I don't add new information to answers, I only edit mistakes / readability issues. New information = new answer in my book.

Comment: The question "[Why would I make a new answer when all I want to do is supplement an existing one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362632/why-would-i-make-a-new-answer-when-all-i-want-to-do-is-supplement-an-existing-on)" has some information about what kind of comments are appropriate to edit in and which are not.

Comment: JSFiddle's license is incompatible with Stack Overflow's. FYI.

Comment: How about if we stop saying "putting words in someone's mouth"? The review history is there to see who wrote what in every post and it's *public*.

Comment: If you do edit it in, make sure to give credit to the original comment, then the popular comment would make sense. "As mentioned by [comment author] in [this comment],....".

Answer (score -7):

Being popular doesn't make a comment correct. If *you* "fix" an answer, then what's to stop anyone from doing it, and making all answers potentially useless? Or at least forcing future visitors to go through the edit history to find out if something went wrong?

If you don't like an answer, ignore it or add a comment, downvote it if you must, or do your own answer. The trail should be open and visible, and not hidden in the edit history.

Comment: "then what's to stop anyone from doing it" The same mechanism as for *any* edits? There are reviews for most people, and even with edit privileges the content owner and everyone *following* will be informed and may rollback edits. Even if *you don't* "fix" an answer –  then what's to stop anyone from doing it? In the end these two things seem unrelated.