# Should answer update edits be accepted or rejected?

Tags: discussion, edits

While reviewing Edit queues I often came across questions where people edit others' code. I generally rejects them as far as they are not about typos.
But sometimes I encounter edits which are kind of updates to an answer, like the answer was posted in 2013 and was edited in 2018 which includes an updated way of doing the same thing that was asked in the question.

IMO, if instead of adding to the answer, they change the answer to the updated codes or text, I should reject it.

So what is the best action in this case?

Comment: The duplicate proposed addresses cases where the author of the answer and the author of the edit are one and the same. In this case it's about reviewing suggested edits by third parties.

Comment: Something like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) would be a bit more appropriate, among other links.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362632/why-would-i-make-a-new-answer-when-all-i-want-to-do-is-supplement-an-existing-on) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer?noredirect=1&lq=1) may also be useful.

Comment: @Braiam I am not asking about updating my own answer. My question is related to be people adding relevant information to other's answers

Comment: @NickA according to your second link, it suggests to answer instead of editing existing answer. On that terms I think edits should be rejected.

Comment: @VivekMishra Yes, that was the point in my link, they should absolutely be rejected. I should've made that more clear.

Comment: @VivekMishra the guidance [to edit your own post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjuaB.png) vs [someone else](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0YTW.png). See any difference?

Comment: @Braiam The fact that the guidelines for how to edit another's post is shown when editing  your own post doesn't mean there isn't a difference, just that SO didn't bother to indicate the difference on the screen because people editing their own posts didn't need to be told that they could make edits that other editors can't.  If you think that it's causing problems, I guess you could post a feature request proposing that those guidelines be removed when editing your own post, but as I've never even heard of it causing problems, you'd need a lot to support such a change.

Comment: @Servy the fact, is a fact. The fact that SE doesn't even consider editing others post differently than editing your own is another fact. The fact that the help center doesn't even phantom a difference between actions is another fact. Facts are good, it tells you the reality of a situation: **any edit that improves the post is welcomed**.

Comment: @Braiam The fact, is a fact.  The fact that SE considers editing others' posts different than editing your own is another fact.  The fact that the help center describes certain actions that aren't appropriate in edits to others' posts is another fact.  Facts are good, it tells you the reality of a situation.  **Not all types of edits to a post are welcomed**, some things should be comments, or posted as a separate answer.