# Why was my edit adding information from another question rejected?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I recently submitted an edit to an already well-established accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21832856. This edit was rejected 2:1 as "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

However I disagee with the reasoning here: the edit is not an address to the author of the post. It is adding additional information to the top answer. Furthermore, it is too substantial to add as a comment. It *could* be added as a separate answer, but the question already has 13 answers, and I felt that writing one additional keyboard shortcut (or 2 including Mac) was not a different-enough approach nor reason to add a new answer.

Comment: Related  discussion  [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5132/23408 "Reviewing edits").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't how we handle duplicates. Editing information from another answer in a different question not only invalidates the original answer, it plagiarizes the copied answer without giving proper credit (no, your comment on the edit reason doesn't really count).

There's two things that should be done instead, assuming they are duplicates (which I am not a VS user so I can't say they are)

1. If the two questions are the same, flag the newer one as a duplicate of the older one
2. Mod flag for a merge (you need #1 done first). That way you get all the answers into the same question

Comment: Hi, perhaps they are candidates for flagging for duplication but the question I edited is a general question, and the question copied is a specific question, but is still applicable to question 1 (i.e. question 2 is a subset of general question 1). Is this cause for merging?

Comment: I can't say for sure (or I would have already voted for duplicate closure). Merging is rare, but if the questions are closely related enough mods can merge them. The hard part is convincing them to do it, but having it closed as a dupe is a strong first step

Comment: Is there a way I can flag for duplication and add a message to reference this meta post and the intention of merging in future?

Comment: Just leave a comment with a link. The only flag with a free-form entry is mod flag, and you need to avoid doing that before closure

Answer (score 2):

> It could be added as a separate answer

You've inadvertently hit the nail on the head here, for two reasons:

1. If your edit could be added as a separate answer and stand on its own, then it should be posted as an answer. It's good of you to acknowledge that there are already many answers (too many users post an answer to popular questions without bothering to read existing answers at all), but that should be of little concern if you have actually new content to add to the answer set.
2. We place a fair bit of stock in post author autonomy; the reason these decliners chose the 'intended to address the author' is likely because of this. Even though the information is useful and makes for a more comprehensive answer, it should be up to the OP to decide whether it belongs in his or her answer. You can make recommendations on improvements all day long *in the comments*, but editing someone else's post to include entirely new or different content is their purview. If OP had marked their answer as a Community Wiki, then it would have most likely been OK to edit so drastically.

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned in the opening post, I didn't go down this route because I thought the answer _would not_ stand on its own. It is not a different answer, merely building on information already present by adding a missing shortcut(s). I appreciate the point of it not being a community wiki however. My background is from editing wikis and having ownership of an answer is a rather interesting and different concept to me.

Comment: And with that context I completely agree with @TylerH that it belongs in a comment as a suggested addition. Personally, I'll occasionally make an edit to my answer based on a beneficial/appropriate recommendation in the comments. However, I think a lot of people would be pretty annoyed if someone went through their answers editing them to "make them better".

Comment: This answer demonstrates that the advice Shog gave a couple of months back hasn't settle in. [I recommend to read it again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362632/why-would-i-make-a-new-answer-when-all-i-want-to-do-is-supplement-an-existing-on#comment553297_362684)

Comment: @Braiam I disagreed with Shog's opinion then and still do now. Shog even admitted the only effective difference is in *when* an author's autonomy should be enforced, before an edit or after an edit. In fact the accepted answer there with a much higher score *also* suggests that it be its own answer rather than an edit. At any rate, the community seems to agree with me more than disagree with me then as it does now. I recommend letting *that* settle in.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit of an edge case. Your edit added and changed a lot of information in the answer, so some reviewers would consider it better as another answer or a comment. However, the purpose of an edit is to improve a post, so some reviewers would approve it because it does significantly improve the answer.  In this case, more reviewers thought it would be better as a separate answer, hence the rejection. Since it got rejected, I would recommend adding an additional answer. Even though it already has a lot of answers, it's okay to add new ones as long as they are worthwhile.

Comment: Hi, I didn't change a lot of information, only added. I did not think that the edit would stand as a separate answer and given the number of answers previously, I opted for editing. I see that given that the answer was not a community wiki this was the wrong approach.

Comment: @kjhf If your answer has significantly different or more information than other answers, it will usually be able to stand on it's own. I think that your edit *should* have been approved, but not everyone thinks so.

Comment: Don't let a couple of reviewers force you to make a nonsense isolated post. This question doesn't need a 14th answer.

Comment: @jpp if there's a lot more information that should be added, then it does need a 14th answer.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain, "Lot more" is subjective. Here it's not *lot more*.

Comment: @jpp that's very debatable.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain, Exactly, `lot more` is a pointless argument. Do what you feel is subjectively right.. Wait, that's exactly what Braiam's done [with his edit that nobody's overturned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29965036/9209546). I'd challenge anyone to start a rollback war, because the edit makes the answer a whole lot better. Oh the irony [meta vs reality discrepancy]...

Comment: @jpp and I don't agree with the edit. If I had enough rep, I probably would have rolled back the edit.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain, Yet the fact remains *nobody else* has rolled it back. *And likely nobody will*. Net gain for SO.

Comment: @jpp yes, nobody else rolled it back. Sometimes higher rep users get away with stuff lower rep users can't.

Answer (score -5):

Too much red tape. SO has a strong wiki culture. For example, you are *encouraged* to change questions to make them more general. Similarly, if you believe you can improve a post without materially changing the author's intent, go ahead. You did the right thing.

If you are in doubt, or if your edit is rejected, you can *try* pinging a user on that Q&A with 2k+ reputation. Their edits stick. The author of the answer will automatically be notified and they, appropriately, have the ability to roll back the edit. Alternatively, you can try joining a SO chat room for an appropriate tag. Failing that, raise the issue on Meta.

If all else fails, just leave a comment. I don't like this option. Comments are ephemeral, and they allows mistakes to propagate without correction. Quality control is biased: you can only upvote comments, not downvote.