# Is a quote of a fraction of answer-code, extended with an alternative, itself an answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Sometimes answers consist solely of these ingredients:

1. A reference to another answer to the same question (with "above", the name of the author, or a hyperlink)
2. A small piece of code quoted from the larger code presented in that other answer
3. An alternative for that code-piece
4. Sometimes: an explanation

When reading such an answer, one needs to first read the other answer to understand what the author is suggesting. The answer is not self-contained.

What to do when reviewing such answers?

NB: I am not questioning the copying of (a piece of) code or the attribution.

#### One actual case

I had commented on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14113507/5459839) – at the time of its [second revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14113507/2) – that it was more appropriate as a comment on the other answer being referred to (actually I don't recall exactly what I wrote), and flagged it as "not an answer".

In this particular case, the first ingredient was even absent (no reference to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12251462/5459839) being quoted from):

> @xxxxxx, or others who don't want to be restricted by format mm/dd/yyyy. All I did was replace
>
> ```
> var dob = new Date(dateString.substring(6,10),
>                    dateString.substring(0,2)-1,                   
>                    dateString.substring(3,5)                  
>                   );
> ```
>
> with
>
> ```
> var dob = new Date(dateString);
> ```
>
> and I could use 2012/09/30 and get the right answer.

The flag was refused, my comment deleted, and the answer improved to its current 3rd version.

#### Appropriate Action?

Should I consider that answers of this type really are to be considered answers, because they actually do make sense when read in the context of the referred-to answer? When reviewing such answers, what is the appropriate action, if any?

Comment: NaA has devolved to be "gibberish only" as far as I can tell. I would think a comment wouldn't be remiss, but if there's no response, not much you can do. Well, *you* can vote to delete it I suppose, but I doubt it's worth it.

Comment: People are told to no edit their own stuff into another answer and instead post their own. If posting your own answer would now also be considered wrong, what option would be left?

Comment: @Tom, I see your point, but then maybe the post should be more self-contained.

Comment: Related: [Why would I make a new answer when all I want to do is supplement an existing one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362632/7795130)

Comment: You already know the answer to this question, the moderator told you.  The site license explicitly allows and encourages this.  Posting a comment or flagging somebody else is not the appropriate way to fix the attribution problem, be sure to edit the post the next time.

Comment: Thank you, @HansPassant, I honestly do not know the answer to the question I ask, as I am not someone who takes moderator's opinions as absolute truth -- I suppose they could make mistakes, not that I am arguing that they did in this case, but it is a possibility. So you are saying that editing is the way to deal with this? What should the edit be? Adding the code of the referred-to answer into it?

Comment: @HansPassant, to be clear, my question is not about the attribution. In fact, in the example I give, there is not even an attribution (Of course, it should better be there). But my question is more about the fact that such answers are not self-contained. They don't make much sense when reading them from the OP's point of view, as they refer to nothing that is in the question.

Comment: If it's not a link-only answer, but the answer does not sufficiently explain the solution by itself, pretty sure flags aren't appropriate, and to respond to it, one should comment or downvote (just like what one would do for an entirely wrong answer)

Comment: Sounds good, @CertainPerformance, ... I just need still to get out of the way why such "answers" should not better be posted as a comment on the referred-to answer. I see that more experienced contributors have the habit of doing it that way. Of course, that does not mean it has to be the only way. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: They *should* be posted as comments rather than answers if they're suggesting tiny improvements on an existing answer without describing any of the other necessary parts of the solution, but unfortunately, some posters don't know what a full answer is expected to contain, and voting/commenting is the only thing available for us to do with incomplete answers